# How E2E test with protractor at other website without angular?

Tags: angular, protractor

I am building test cases, one of them is testing with protractor at other website and I only get error messages

Angular CLI: 7.3.8
Node: 11.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.14

```
beforeEach(function() {
  browser.get('http://xxx.xx/');
});

it('should have a title', function() {
  expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('XXX');
});
```

I expect that protractor regonise title of website and I get message "Failed: javascript error: angular is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Protractor and WebdriverJS is that before performing each command Protractor waits for Angular specific $http and $timeout tasks to complete.

However, if you use Protractor in non-angular app you will notice that it simply doesn't do anything. As per my understanding, protractor keeps looking for these tasks without any luck

This feature can be manually disabled using `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`.

Once you disable you can interact with non-angular page. But make sure add functions that would wait for the page to load.

Thus you'll have something like

```
it('should have a title', function() {
  browser.get(angularPage);

  // disable waiting for angular
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

  // open non angular page
  $redirectingLink.click();

  // do whatever you want here
  expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('XXX');

  // enable the feature back on
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
});
```